# Elm: How to define a function that performs a request with message as parameter

Tags: elm

In Elm 0.18, how can I define a function that performs a request, which takes as parameter the **message** for the update function when receiving the response?

The following code:

```
mypost : String -> String -> msg -> Cmd msg
mypost url csrf mymsg =
    Http.request
        { method = "POST"
        , headers = [ Http.header "X-CSRFToken" csrf ]
        , url = url
        , body = Http.emptyBody
        , expect = Http.expectJson mydecoder
        , timeout = Nothing
        , withCredentials = False
        }
        |> RemoteData.sendRequest
        |> Cmd.map mymsg
```

doesn't compile:

> The argument to function `map` is causing a mismatch.
>
> 124|            Cmd.map m
>                           ^ 
>   Function `map` is expecting the argument to be:
>
> ```
> a -> msg
> ```
>
> But it is:
>
> ```
> msg
> ```
>
> Hint: It looks like a function needs 1 more argument.

And what if the msg takes a parameter? for example:

```
|> Cmd.map (mymsg myParamTomymsg)
```

This has led me to having lot's of code duplication, there must be a better way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is written assuming you're using the standard Http package. If you're new to Elm, I'd recommend to play around with it first and the use open source packages.

#### TL;DR

The type of `mymsg` in your code is supposed to be `a -> msg`, where type variable `a` is the same type as the value produced by a decoder `mydecoder`

```
mypost : String -> String -> (a -> msg) -> Cmd msg
```

You have to specify the type explicitly and replace `a` with the type of response.

### Longer explanation

In other words, you have to explicitly say that the first argument passed to [Http.send](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http#send) is a function, that maps a response to a message.

When you define a Union Type, the `Msg` is the name of your new type and `NoOp` with `Update` are the actual values which can act as constructors of values of `Msg` type.

```
type Msg
    = NoOp
    | Update String
```

By using `Update "Hello"` in the code we create a value of `Msg` type, where a string `"Hello"` is tagged with a tag `Update` The same thing happens in [Http.send](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http#send), except that the type of tagged value is expected to be a [Result.](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Result)

The type of `Update` is implied to be `String -> Msg`

Let's have a look at the type annotation definition for [Http.send:](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http#send)

```
send : (Result Error a -> msg) -> Request a -> Cmd msg
```

Here's an example of a [generic GET request:](https://github.com/halfzebra/elm-opentdb/blob/1a75e019045178409688ab856d1f51c87afe20a1/src/Request/TriviaQuestions.elm#L53)

```
get : Int -> Difficulty -> (Result Error TriviaResult -> msg) -> Cmd msg
get amount difficulty msg =
    Http.get (triviaRequestUrl amount difficulty) decoder
        |> Http.send msg
```

### If you're using [remotedata](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/krisajenkins/remotedata/latest)

You have to fix your type definition annotation:

```
myget1 : (WebData HttpBin -> msg) -> Cmd msg
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, though I still can't make it work, I added this [ellie example](https://ellie-app.com/48cqdkb2znHa1/0) that doesn't compile to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: @FranciscoDibar just replace the type annotation definition with `myget1 : (WebData HttpBin -> msg) -> Cmd msg`, I did not realize that you're using [remotedata.](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/krisajenkins/remotedata/latest)

Comment: Awesome! now it works :)
Next step is how to send the msg with a parameter (see last part of question)

Comment: Answering myself for params, define i.e. myget1 : (Int -> RemoteData.WebData HttpBin -> msg) -> Cmd msg